# JSF 2.0: cookies are not persisted immediately after AJAX call, HTTP request required

Tags: ajax, jsf, cookies, jsf-2, immediate-attribute

Ajax call performed in order to remove item from shopping cart - `removeOrder()` method is called

UI `removeOrder()` call(JSF&Primefaces):

```
<p:commandButton value="clean" actionListener="#{showProducts.removeOrder}"
   process="@form" update="@form,:ccId:cCart:ccSizeId,:ccId:cCart:ccTotId" immediate="true">
<f:attribute name="remove" value="#{cart.name}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Backend `removeOrder()` call(managed bean)

```
public void removeOrder(ActionEvent e) {
        String productName = (String) e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("remove");
        Product p = getProductByName(productName);
        inCart.remove(p);
        persistCookies();
        emptyCartNotifier();
        totalRendered();
    }
```

Here cookies is persisted,output of this method as is expected,Cookie array contains cookies with empty values,that's OK:

```
private void persistCookies() {
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

    String ids = "";

    for (Product prod : inCart) {
        // TODO change logic to support real count,for now 1 is available only
        ids += prod.getId() + ";" + prod.getCount() + "_";
    }

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(SC_COOKIE, ids);
    Cookie cookie2 = new Cookie(SC_SIZE, String.valueOf(inCart.size()));
    Cookie cookie3 = new Cookie(SC_TOTAL_PRICE, String.valueOf(subTotal));
    cookie3.setPath("/");
    cookie3.setMaxAge(TWO_WEEKS);
    httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie3);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookie.setMaxAge(TWO_WEEKS);
    cookie2.setPath("/");
    cookie2.setMaxAge(TWO_WEEKS);

    httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
    httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie2);

}
```

Here problem occurred, the method emptyCartNotifier() see ***non-empty "previous" Cookies*** array

```
private String emptyCartNotifier() {

    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();
    boolean isCookiePresent = false;
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie c : cookies) {
            if (SC_COOKIE.equals(c.getName()) && (!c.getValue().isEmpty())) {
                isCookiePresent = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (inCart.isEmpty() && (!isCookiePresent)) {
        emptyCartNotifier = "you cart is empty";
        isFormRendered = false;
    } else {
        emptyCartNotifier = "";
        isFormRendered = true;
    }
    return emptyCartNotifier;
}
```

After any HTTP request performed, that Cookie array is really cleaned up.

As I see , clash is:
after AJAX call cleans cookie, that `HttpServletRequest` contains non-empty cookie until new HTTP request performed(user submit button or go by link).

Is there solution or good practice for immediate cookie management,when web-app combines AJAX and non-AJAX calls?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait, what? In `emptyCartNotifier`, You are calling `getCookies` on the `HttpRequest` object, which is supposed to contain the cookies that *were in the HTTP request* that triggered your method, so of course you don't see changes until the next request.

Comment: yes,that is a question,how to friend HTTP and non-HTTP in this case

Comment: Oh, I see, HttpServletResponse stupidly does not have a way to access the cookies that you set before... Return a `Cookie[]` from `persistCookies` and pass that to `emptyCartNotifier`?

Answer (score 2):

Your cookie problem is one thing, but I think there is a much easier way to get things done.

In your page, just replace the pages you mention with this:

```
<p:commandButton value="clean" action="#{showProducts.removeOrder(cart)}"
   process="@form" update="@form,:ccId:cCart:ccSizeId,:ccId:cCart:ccTotId" immediate="true" />
```

Backing bean (e.g. session scoped):

```
private double subtotal; // don't forget getter and setter

public void removeOrder(Product product) {
        inCart.remove(product);
        // calculate subtotal
}
```

I guess you show the subtotal and maybe list all products after calling *removeOrder*. Just recalculate subtotal after removing the product, and make sure the shopping cart is refreshed (*update* attribute).

This code is simple enough and easy to understand, and yet does everything you need. No need to "manually" manage cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting your cookies `setHttpOnly(true)`, but the question is why would you need "ajax-scoped" cookie persistence at all?

Why not use local variables in your view/request/session scoped beans? They're actually designed for that sort of tasks. If you want additional cookie persistence you do it in corresponding setters or action methods.

Comment: Hi Osw,do you mean to use class fields instead of variables within methods?

Comment: about "ajax-scoped" cookies- yes exactly, that's I need for now

Comment: @sergionni, right, storing data in bean's variables, they're gettable/settable within your scope. And cookies will be involved only when user leaves the page, just as you have described in your question.